# Mockito OracleConnection

Tags: java, spring, oracle, junit, mockito

I am trying to test old pure Spring app. I am trying to test class which is data provider and uses OracleConnection. I am using Mocikto for this but any time when database conection related code is executed it throws NPE. I know that i could change parseSQLErrorDB to public and do kind of Mockito.when.then but that is not the point..

My test:

```
public class DataProviderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DataProvider dataProvider;

    @Mock
    PoolDataSource dataSource;

    @Mock
    OracleCallableStatement oracleCallableStatement;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(dataProvider, "parseSQLErrorFuntion", "String you want to inject");
        Mockito.when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(Mockito.any(Connection.class));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void parseSQLErrorUnconditionalTest() throws SQLException {
        String messageFromDB = "Error message from database";
        String expected = messageFromDB;
        String actual = dataProvider.parseSQLError("Undefined");
        Mockito.verify(oracleCallableStatement, Mockito.times(1)).execute();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

And DataProvider:

```
public class DataProvider {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataProvider.class);

    // private OracleDataSource dataSource;
    private PoolDataSource dataSource;
    private boolean isAthenticate;
    private String parseSQLErrorFuntion;
    private boolean isInitialized;
    private boolean ignoreMsgLenLimit;

    public DataProvider() {
        super();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        OracleConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (OracleConnection) dataSource.getConnection();
           
            loggerInfoAboutDatabase(conn);
            if (!testParseSQLErrorDB(conn)) {
                logger.warn("Brak: parseSQLErrorFuntion");
                parseSQLErrorFuntion = null;
            }
            isInitialized = true;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error("{}", ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } finally {
            closeConnection(null, conn);
        }
    }

    public String parseSQLError(String errorString) {
        if (errorString != null) {
            return parseSQLErrorDB(errorString);
        }
        return errorString;
    }

    private String parseSQLErrorDB(String errorString) {

        OracleCallableStatement cs = null;
        OracleConnection conn = null;
        String callS = "";
        try {
            conn = getConnection();
            ...rest of code
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.error("Error parseSQLError: {} ; error: {}", callS, ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeConnection(cs, conn);
        }
        return rv;
    }

    

    public void close() {
    }

    public OracleConnection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        ...
    }

    public OracleConnection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        ...
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Connection conn) {
        ...
    }

    public static void closeConnection(CallableStatement cs, Connection conn) {
        ...
    }

    public static void closeConnection(Statement stmt, ResultSet rs, Connection conn) {
        ...
    }


    private void loggerInfoAboutDatabase(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
        logger.info("=============");
        logger.info("Database Product Name is : " + dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductName());
        logger.info("Database Product Version : " + dbMetaData.getDatabaseProductVersion());
        logger.info("JDBC Driver Name          : " + dbMetaData.getDriverName());
        logger.info("JDBC Driver Version is    : " + dbMetaData.getDriverVersion());
        logger.info("JDBC Driver Major Version : " + dbMetaData.getDriverMajorVersion());
        logger.info("JDBC Driver Minor Version : " + dbMetaData.getDriverMinorVersion());
        logger.info("=============");
    }

    ..getters, setters

}
```

When i execute this line in setUp() block

```
Mockito.when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(Mockito.any(Connection.class));
```

I got:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at pl.sygnity.common.db.DataProviderTest.setUp(DataProviderTest.java:47)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

But when I comment this out, it executes methods and throws NPE on loggerInfoAboutDatabase method..
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pl.test.common.db.DataProvider.loggerInfoAboutDatabase(DataProvider.java:186)
    at pl.test.common.db.DataProvider.init(DataProvider.java:49)
    at pl.test.common.db.DataProvider.getConnection(DataProvider.java:146)
    at pl.test.common.db.DataProvider.parseSQLErrorDB(DataProvider.java:90)
    at pl.test.common.db.DataProvider.parseSQLError(DataProvider.java:74)
    at pl.test.common.db.DataProviderTest.parseSQLErrorUnconditionalTest(DataProviderTest.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at
```

Any ideas here? Can I fake somehow this PoolDatasource and all related stuff?

Comment: I think you should step back and read a tutorial about mockito. To me it looks like you assume how this or that element of mockito might work, and then wrote down plenty of code that actually doesn't make sense. For example: why are you using Mockito.any() in that thenReturn() call?! You should use that call to have the mock return a specific object?!

Comment: I am using any() because I don't want any of these values, I just need them to be not null. How can I possibly mock mock/predefine values used from loggerInfoAboutDatabase? This is only void method for logging purposes. I cannot skipt it also because it is private method and I am stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: any() doesn't create objects! It is an argument matcher call. If you don't care about that object, just call mock(whatever . class) instead.

Comment: Again: don't assume what your mockito calls do. Read a tutorial, and read the javadoc for the methods you are using.

Comment: As Ghost pointed out you don't understand what your line does. `thenReturn()` is used when you want to mock a specific method and **return** a particular thing. So using `any()` in the `thenReturn()` doesn't make sense. Try to find how to pass parameters to a method with `when()` and use `any()` to 'ignore' them.

Comment: Thanks guys. @PhilippeB. your hint was the point.

Comment: @Mateusz Gebroski, it would be useful if you could put the solution as an answer with explanation instead of just editing the question and also you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @ Mateusz Gebroski, Thanks for considering and you also can accept the answer which looks nicer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to test it.
Basically I am mocking every nested objects that are used during program execution.

```
public class DataProviderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DataProvider dataProvider;

    @Mock
    OracleConnection oracleConnection;
    
    @Mock
    DatabaseMetaData databaseMetadata;
    
    @Mock
    PoolDataSource dataSource;

    @Mock
    OracleCallableStatement oracleCallableStatement;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(dataProvider, "parseSQLErrorFuntion", "String you want to inject");
        Mockito.when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(oracleConnection);
        Mockito.when(oracleConnection.getMetaData()).thenReturn(databaseMetadata);
        Mockito.when(oracleConnection.prepareCall(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(oracleCallableStatement);
    }

    
    @Test
    public void parseSQLErrorUnconditionalTest() throws SQLException {
        String messageFromDB = "Error message from database";
        String expected = messageFromDB;
        Mockito.when(oracleCallableStatement.getString(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(messageFromDB);
        String actual = dataProvider.parseSQLError("Undefined");
        Mockito.verify(oracleCallableStatement, Mockito.times(2)).execute();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
}
```